# Error while loading Keras 2.4.3 for Tensorflow 2.2

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm receiving this error message when importing keras: Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher. Install TensorFlow via `pip install tensorflow'

When I downgrade to keras 2.3.1, I receive the following error "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal: A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed."  Help!

```
import struct
print("Python version: " + str(8 * struct.calcsize("P")))
print("loading keras.layers...")
from keras.layers import Input, LSTM, Dense
print("loading keras.models...")
from keras.models import Model
print("loading nltk.corpus...")
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
```

Windows Server 2012 R12 x64 (VM)

python 3.8.3 x64

Keras 3.4.1 or 3.2.1

tensorflow 2.2

C++ redistribution

No GPU

Comment: I downgraded to python 3.7.8 and installed tensorflow 2.2/keras 3.4.1 and same problem occurred

Comment: did you try keras from tensorflow library?

Comment: @JaySabir I'm trying that right now...standby

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with keras, it is that when importing TensorFlow you get an error about DLLs (the classic one).

Comment: @JaySabir after trying that, im back to the second error message that I posted which is ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.  Whats up with that?

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy what do you mean....the classic one.  I imported the keras libs that are embedded in tensorflow and received: ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal.  Any suggestions?

Comment: That is the classic TensorFlow error (ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal), if you search in SO you will see a lot of people having this issue constantly. It happens because the TensorFlow  native DLL has some unmet dependencies).

Comment: @Dr. Snoopy how do you solve that classic tensorflow error?  I've tried almost everything

Comment: @JaySabir I receive the same problem when using the keras lib inside the tensorflow packages. "ImportError: DLL load failed while importing _pywrap_tensorflow_internal."

Comment: I'd try reinstalling C++ redistributable or updating it to a newer version. Also, check your os environment variable you might find something missinng there.

Comment: @JaySabir I've reinstalled C++ redistributable so many times and rebooted, its crazy.  It works fine on a similar computer, but I need it working on the server.  I've narrowed the problem down to MSVCP140_1.DLL file.  When I remove that file from C:\windows\system32\ directory, the error message changes to "Keras requires TensorFlow 2.2 or higher." on both computers.  777 permissions on both computers, the same installed apps and C++ red..

Comment: I've uninstalled the recommended C++ redistrib by tensorflow and upgraded to Visual Studio 2019 and selected to install the C++ 2015-2019 redistrib and still encountered the same problem.  I've opened up a ticket with tensorflow about this problem: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/41991

Comment: update tensorflow